# Adding to a mySQL database

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to PHP so this is probably a pretty easy answer. Anyways I have a mysql table called `cities` with `10` columns with different city names, then I have a html drop down menu with each of the cities listed. Once they submit I want to add 1 to the mysql table to whichever city they selected. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Search on your favourite seach engine PHP + MySQL. You will find hundreds of tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the tutorial from me so that you can able to post it with this code or even you try to modify this code based on your needs.

Here's the code created on php code.

THE HTML CODE

```
<select name="KODECITIES">
     <option value=0 selected>- CITIES Code -</option>
     <?php
         $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
         if (!$con)
         {
             die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
         }
         mysql_select_db("CITIES TABLE", $con);

         $result = mysql_query("SELECT Kode FROM CITIES");
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
             echo "<option value=$row[0]>$row[0]</option>";
         }

         mysql_close($con);
     ?>
</select>
```

Then inside your php :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitbutton']))
    {
        $kodecities = $_POST['KODECITIES'];
        echo $kodecities;
    }
?>
```